# How do I make the chat show idle immediately?

Tags: gmail, google-talk

When my email is left idle, my chat button shows green for a long time (for about 20 minutes) before turning orange, meaning I am available although I am away doing something.

How I make the green turn to orange almost immediately once I leave the email idle?

Comment: I doubt that’s possible, but I don’t know for sure so I won’t post this as an answer. However, I think the old (Talk) desktop client offered the option to set the idle time.

Comment: are you talking about the desktop application or web interface?

Comment: Currently there is no option in the chat settings to make the chat as idle once you leave the email.It will take 15 min to update the status as idle

Answer (score 1):

From: [Changing your status - Google Chat Help](https://support.google.com/chat/answer/161809?hl=en)

> Yellow: Idle. Your status automatically changes to idle when you're
>   away from your computer for 15 minutes. You can't manually select to
>   appear idle